# wIntegrate add text to dbgrid column headers

Tags: universe, rocket

Well the documentation is non-existent on this one, which would seem a pretty straight forward things to want to do. Am trying to add column header text to row 0 and it simply is not playing ball.

```
  * Load up the Column
  REC = "Cell 0,1":VM:"Cell 0,2"
  REC<-1> = "Deal#":VM:"Deal"
  CALL WIN.DBSETPRP(DLGNAME, "Grid1","ColText",REC)
```

The app keeps falling over on dialog box load with an Error 3, which I figure is to do with this block of code. Can;t figure out the syntax.

Comment: Never used Wintegrate, but I poked around a bit in  https://docs.rocketsoftware.com/nxt/gateway.dll/RKBnew20%2Fwintegrate%2Fprevious%20versions%2Fv6.3.7%2Fwintegrate_hostsubroutinesrefguide_v637.pdf . Maybe try using WIN.DBGETPRP with the same parameters and see what the value of the property is to begin with? Good Luck.

Comment: Hey Van, finally got this one worked out. You need to use both manuals, one gives the routines to call and the other lists the properties and methods of each control. so to load I needed to:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
COLTITLES = "Title A, Tittle B, Title C"
CALL WIN.DBSETPRPR(DBNAME, GRIDNAME, "ColText", COLTITLES)
```